# symfony2 form templating

Tags: webforms, symfony, twig

I want to render a form. HTML for a field row should be like this:

```
<li class="text">
  <label for="fieldname">
  <div>
    <input type="text" ... />
  </div>
</li>
```

when the field type is text the li.class have to be the same.

I overwrite the field_row block:

```
{% block field_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <li class="text">
        {{ form_label(form, label|default(null)) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </li>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_row %}
```

but how to replace the class value?

Comment: I do not understand the question: Do you want to replace the li class dynamically when the form widget is TextType or do you want to add a class attribute to the form widget itself ?

Comment: yes. the 1. one. I want to replace the li class to "text", "numer", "largetext" or "something_else"

Answer (score 0):

You can try to attach a public member to your FormType class (If present...) and call it from the twig template.

Maybe also the attributes array of a form can be accessed in a twig template...

```
class YourType extends AbstractType
{
    public $class = 'text';

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('fieldname');
    }
    //...
}
```

And

```
{% block field_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <li class="{{ form.class }}">
        {{ form_label(form, label|default(null)) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </li>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_row %}
```

Comment: Yes but I want something like this: <li class="text">...</li><li class="number">...</li>

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the "field" word with the name of the type you want to modify.

You do it like this for text fields, but it's the same for any type:

```
{% block text_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <li class="text">
        {{ form_label(form, label|default(null)) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </li>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock text_row %}
```

or like this for textareas:

```
{% block textarea_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <li class="textarea">
        {{ form_label(form, label|default(null)) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </li>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock textarea_row %}
```

The important part is the block name, it should be the same as the name of the type you want to modify. The "field_row" is the default for all field types if there is no exact matching name.

This also works for form-types you defined yourself (the ones that inherit from AbstractType, that's why it's important you add a name to your form-types, see http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes).